# .htaccess multiple variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't find the best way to make things work with .htaccess.

My current .htaccess looks like this and it's now almost does what I want:

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ ?page=about [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ ?page=home [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ?page=about&what=contact [NC]
RewriteRule ^browse/?$ ?page=browse [NC]
RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?page=make&make=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^browse/(.+)/(.+)/?$ ?page=browser&make=$1&ser=$2 [NC,L]
```

Only downside of this is when in 5th line url has a space which is replaced by %20 and % brokes it.

I think structure of my site is understandable from rewrite rules, but I'll try to make it even more clear. So 4th line redirects to BROWSE page where are many links like "browse/Master Category" (some of them have spaces in the middle of them). Clicking on that links brings me to page MAKE and 5th line of .htaccess. Now URLs without "`%20`" works fine in this case. And in those pages there are links like "`browse/MasterCategory/Other Category`" which brings me to page BROWSER and have two wariables in itself. If I try to put "`.+`" into 5th line instead of "`[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`" it brokes 6th line abd BROWSER page doesn't get it's variables.

I still think this might not be very clear, but my broken English can't describe this more precise. I hope somebody can still help me.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` does not match spaces. If you want to match a space, you can escape it like this `([a-zA-Z0-9_\ -]+)`. Alternativelly, you can match everything but a slash `([^/]+)`. Don't have means to test it atm.

Comment: I tried adding space before, but it didn't worked for me. Now I did the ([^/]+) and it looks like it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to sum up all characters that can appear in the variable, you can also simply match all characters except the delimiter. In this case that is the slash. You can do that with `[^/]+`. The whole rule would look like

```
RewriteRule ^browse/([^/]+)/?$ ?page=make&make=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^browse/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?page=browser&make=$1&ser=$2 [NC,L]
```